# using redisson local caching with RLO

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am using redisson as a redis client solution.
looking for a solution of local caching implementation for complex java classes.
Is it possible to use RLO in the following way:

```
RLocalCachedMap<String, ComplexClass> map
```

while ComplexClass will be implemented as RLO and attached to the RLiveObjectService as expected.

Thanks!